# On primes between $k$ and $k!$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

I have the following homework question:

"Show that for $k\geq 4$ between $k$ and $k!$ there always exists a prime number of the form $4n+3$."

How can one prove it?

Comment: Please add the condition $k>2$

Answer (score 5):

**Hint:** Look at the prime divisors of $k!-1$, and note that $k!-1\equiv -1(\bmod. 4)$ for $k\geq 4$.